# Primefaces: Remove Specify Icon submenu component

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I remove the Specify Icon in Primefaces? I tried the following code:

```
<p:menbar>
<p:submenu label="File">
......
</p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

On the right, the label of the submenu's Triangle Icon, it's necessary for me to style the icon.

```
.ui-icon{display:none;}
```

Unfortunately, it will affect all icons. I don't know why `display: none` is only applied to Specify Icon.

Comment: Please take some time to learn CSS. It is one of the foundations of web development. And since JSF is in this regard nothing more than an html/css generator, you should learn those basics before doing actual full blown development

Answer (score 1):

Try this !!

```
<p:menubar>
   <p:submenu label="File" styleClass="submenu">
    ......
   </p:submenu> 
</p:menubar>
```

Use the CSS rule below:

```
.submenu .ui-menuitem-link > .ui-icon-triangle-1-s{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to replace the icon by another one? Can't find that in the docs...

Comment: @JavierCabero see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401103/how-to-change-primefaces-submenu-default-icons) for changing the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "**styleClass**" attribute of [p:submenu](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/submenu.html) to apply the CSS rule on [p:submenu](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/submenu.html).

```
<p:menubar>
    <p:submenu label="File" styleClass="submenu">
    ......
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

Use following CSS rule:

```
.submenu .ui-icon-triangle-1-s{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: And how would you change the icon to another one?

Comment: You can do like this :
background-image: url('images/image_name.png');
 background-position: 12px 5px;
 width: 30px;